# Efficient way to calculate averages, standard deviations from a txt file

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, python, pandas

Here is a copy of what one of many txt files looks like.

```
Class 1:
Subject A:
posX posY posZ  x(%)  y(%)
  0   2    0    81    72
  0   2   180   63    38
 -1  -2    0    79    84
 -1  -2   180   85    95
  .   .    .    .     .
Subject B:
posX posY posZ  x(%)   y(%)
  0   2     0    71     73
 -1  -2     0    69     88   
  .   .     .    .      .
Subject C:
posX  posY posZ x(%)   y(%)
  0    2    0    86     71
 -1   -2    0    81     55
  .    .    .     .     .
Class 2:
Subject A:
posX posY posZ  x(%)  y(%)
  0   2    0    81    72
 -1  -2    0    79    84
  .   .    .    .     .
```

- The number of classes, subjects, row entries all vary.
- Class1-Subject A always has posZ entries that have 0 alternating with 180
- Calculate average of x(%), y(%) by class and by subject
- Calculate standard deviation of x(%), y(%) by class and by subject
- Also ignore the posZ of 180 row when calculating averages and std_deviations

I have developed an unwieldly solution in excel (using macro's and VBA) but I would rather go for a more optimal solution in python.

numpy is very helpful but the .mean(), .std() functions only work with arrays- I am still researching some more into it as well as the panda's groupby function.

I would like the final output to look as follows (1. By Class, 2. By Subject)

```
 1. By Class                 
             X     Y                      
 Average                        
 std_dev     

 2. By Subject  
             X     Y
 Average
 std_dev
```

Comment: if you are already using `numpy`; take a look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) group-by capabilities.

Comment: Is your issue reading the data file into something you can work with? Or in getting the output with a structure you already have read in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think working with dictionaries (and a list of dictionaries) is a good way to get familiar with working with data in python. To format your data like this, you'll want to read in your text files and define variables line by line.

To start:

```
for line in infile:
    if line.startswith("Class"):
        temp,class_var = line.split(' ')
        class_var = class_var.replace(':','')   
    elif line.startswith("Subject"):
        temp,subject = line.split(' ')
        subject = subject.replace(':','')
```

This will create variables that correspond to the current class and current subject. Then, you want to read in your numeric variables. A good way to just read in those values is through a `try` statement, which will try to make them into integers.

```
    else:
        line = line.split(" ")
        try:
            keys = ['posX','posY','posZ','x_perc','y_perc']
            values = [int(item) for item in line]
            entry = dict(zip(keys,values))
            entry['class'] = class_var
            entry['subject'] = subject
            outputList.append(entry)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This will put them into dictionary form, including the earlier defined class and subject variables, and append them to an outputList. You'll end up with this:

```
[{'posX': 0, 'x_perc': 81, 'posZ': 0, 'y_perc': 72, 'posY': 2, 'class': '1', 'subject': 'A'},
{'posX': 0, 'x_perc': 63, 'posZ': 180, 'y_perc': 38, 'posY': 2, 'class': '1', 'subject': 'A'}, ...]
```

etc.

You can then average/take SD by subsetting the list of dictionaries (applying rules like excluding posZ=180 etc.). Here's for averaging by Class:

```
classes = ['1','2']
print "By Class:"
print "Class","Avg X","Avg Y","X SD","Y SD"
for class_var in classes:   

    x_m = np.mean([item['x_perc'] for item in output if item['class'] == class_var and item['posZ'] != 180])
    y_m = np.mean([item['y_perc'] for item in output if item['class'] == class_var and item['posZ'] != 180])
    x_sd = np.std([item['x_perc'] for item in output if item['class'] == class_var and item['posZ'] != 180])
    y_sd = np.std([item['y_perc'] for item in output if item['class'] == class_var and item['posZ'] != 180])

    print class_var,x_m,y_m,x_sd,y_sd
```

You'll have to play around printed output to get exactly what you want, but this should get you started.